# Multiplexing AC voltages

Tags: ac, relay, multiplexer, rectifier

I have three 24V AC lines (from a sprinkler controller) that I need to multiplex into two 12 DC lines. Here's the circuit I designed, with the AC inputs on the left, and the DC outputs on the right.
The AC inputs have a common, and the outputs have a common negative.
Each input converts AC to DC using a bridge rectifier (when active), and then uses a 7812 to reduce to 12V, which then drives a 12v relay. The purpose of the relays is to multiplex the DC outputs.

When I wire up each rectifier/7812/relay section separately, it works. However, when I use all the sections together, all the relays activate, and all the 7812s are showing 12V out.

I understand digital electronics pretty well, but analog circuits are not my strength.

I'm thinking that the commons are causing the problem, and that pull-down resistors, or diodes might solve the problem, but I'm not sure.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: What is expected to be the load current on 12V? Linear regulators like you've shown may be prohibitively inefficient.

Comment: Are you saying that when _only one_ 24VAC input is active and the other two are 0V, you still see all three regulators output 12VDC?

Comment: When you use all of the sections together, what are the AC inputs doing? Are they all active, none active, or only one or more active?

Comment: I'm not sure the exact load current. It is six 12v relays, which de-multiplex the signal back to 24v lines. I don't have the datasheet on the relays, and can't find it online.

Comment: Yes, when only one 24VAC input is active, and the other two are not connected, I still see all three regulators output 12VDC

Comment: One AC supply is full wave rectified into its reservoir capacitor. But because it shares a "Neutral" with the other two, that "Neutral" is half-wave rectified into the other two reservoir caps; providing (with more ripple because half wave) power for their 12V regulators.

Comment: That makes sense. Any suggestions how to prevent that?

Comment: Can you make a truth table for all AC input combinations (eight) and your two wanted output signals? It would help our (my) understanding a lot.

Comment: @async8192, are you trying to "**binary code**" four AC input states 000, 001, 010, 100 on two DC lines + return (rather than "multiplex" which implies something completely different)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a diode to the shared common on the AC input. This prevents the negative voltage from getting through to the circuit. Thanks to all the comments and suggestions, especially Brian Drummond for the clue about the common being half-wave rectified into the reservoir caps. Also, hacktastical for a more efficient circuit. When I added the diode to the common on his 2nd circuit, it worked great.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fImxYY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Bridge rectifiers shown as individual diodes for clarity.*

In this setup the circuit is simplified by using 24 V AC coiled relays for the logic and one common voltage regulator to generate the DC if any of the AC inputs is on.

A single contact of RLY3 can be used if it's contact feeds A and B via a diode to each line.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I grok this.

We'll call the three AC lines A, B and C for the top to to the bottom. Relays we'll call K1 - K4. DC lines we'll call X and Y.

Let's see what we have here:

```
  C  B  A:  K1 K2 K3 K4   X Y
  0  0  0:   0  0  0  0   0 0
  0  0  1:   1  0  0  0   1 0
  0  1  0:   0  1  0  0   0 1
  0  1  1:   1  1  0  0   1 1

  1  0  0:   0  0  1  1   1 1
  1  0  1:   0  1  1  1   1 1
  1  1  0:   1  0  1  1   1 1
  1  1  1:   1  1  1  1   1 1
```

Is that right? So basically when AC line "C" is on, then both +12 lines are on?

Ok, then there's a simpler way: diode logic, and use resistors to set the coil drive. Here's how I would interpret that:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPwh9H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You could also realize it this way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgyb9v.png)</sup>

Comment: No can do. The AC feeds share a common.

Comment: And that matters... why? Think about it.

Comment: I retract that statement and wonder why I said it! I think you initially drew them as independent AC sources and it reminded me of a problem I saw many years ago. Carry on!

Comment: I'm still unsure about what OP means by "multiplex" though. I just reverse-engineered their intent.

Comment: I suspect OP meant "binary code" four states 000, 001, 010, 100 on two lines.

Comment: Correct.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexing

Comment: @hacktastical Thank you for the more efficient approach. Your truth table is correct. However, I just wired up your second circuit, and both 7812s output 12vdc no matter which input I put 24vAC on. Brian Drummond above suggested that the common AC line is the culprit, charging both reservoir capacitors - one with full wave rectified DC and one with half-wave rectified DC. That makes sense to my limited understanding....

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to use half-wave rectifiers:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbRmg0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You have already testified that ghalf wavwe rectification is sufficient with your description of the fault in your original circuit.  you don't need any relays.

This is only good for low power devices like LED indicators, if you need to run devices needing several watts use something like this which uses half-wave rectification to run the relays and full wave rectification to power the outputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO1vAV.png)</sup>